# Is there any Islamic source that says whether it is permissible to bury animals?

Tags: animals

Is there any information in the Qur'an or from Prophet Muhammad (SAW) or any other reliable source regarding whether it is permissible to bury animals?  I've looked at a few previous questions, but none necessarily have addressed the question.

If not, are there any expectations regarding what to do with dead animals we find?  Specifically in regard to those that can't be used for any expedient purposes (eg. source for food, clothing, etc).  What about dead animals such as those found in places where they distract ongoers (such as dead animals on a sidewalk or road)?

So I suppose as an overall question, in Islam, what should we do with dead animals we find?

Answer (score 1):

#### A story taken from [Quran 5:27-31](http://quran.com/5/27-31).

> And recite to them the story of Adam's two sons, in truth, when they both offered a sacrifice [to Allah ], and it was accepted from one of them but was not accepted from the other. Said [the latter], "I will surely kill you." Said [the former], "Indeed, Allah only accepts from the righteous [who fear Him].[5:27]
>
> If you should raise your hand against me to kill me - I shall not raise my hand against you to kill you. Indeed, I fear Allah , Lord of the worlds.[5:28]
>
> Indeed I want you to obtain [thereby] my sin and your sin so you will be among the companions of the Fire. And that is the recompense of wrongdoers."[5:29]
>
> And his soul permitted to him the murder of his brother, so he killed him and became among the losers.[5:30]
>
> **Then Allah sent a crow searching in the ground to show him how to hide the disgrace of his brother.** He said, "O woe to me! Have I failed to be like this crow and hide the body of my brother?" And he became of the regretful.[5:31]

This story tell that the `...crow searching in the ground to show him how to hide the disgrace of his brother...`, which probably means: `the crow dug a hole and buried another dead corpse to show him`. So I hope it is correct to bury dead animals

Answer (score 0):

In Islam, an action that is not expressly prohibited or discouraged is considered halal.  You don't need an explicit source to permit something, since everything is considered permissible by default.

The Qur'an condemns those who forbid what Allah has not forbidden where it says,

> Say, [O Muhammad], "Bring forward your witnesses who will testify that Allah has prohibited this." And if they testify, do not testify with them. And do not follow the desires of those who deny Our verses and those who do not believe in the Hereafter, while they equate [others] with their Lord.

Unless you know of evidence that burying an animal or dealing with it however you want is forbidden, there is no reason to believe that it is.

Comment: Which ayah is this? Please add it.

Answer (score 0):

**Well**

There is no straight saying in Qur'an or in Hadith about burying an animal so it is on you weather you do it or not.

Answer (score 0):

Lets use common sense. Animals di not have the status of human beings but deserve love respect and care. Bury animals which is easy to do and the rest goes to feed other animal. It is through ordinance that in the wild animals feed on each other.